# How execute Link Router after to set useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to make a program when I clicked some button, router deliver button's information to after page.

Button component is here.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

function Restaurant_Item({rlist}) {
const [rstData, setResData] = useState([]);
const [linkName, setLinkName] = useState("abc");
let rlist_tmp = [];

const goDetail = (rkey) => {
    setResData(rlist[rkey])
    setLinkName(rlist[rkey].restName)
}

for (let rkey in rlist) {
    rlist_tmp.push(
        <Link to={{
            pathname :"/restaurant_result",
            search : `?sort=${linkName}`,
            state: {data : rstData}
            }}>
            <div className="rst_list_cell" onClick={() => goDetail(rkey)}>
                <div key={rkey}>
                    <button className="rst_list_name">
                        {rlist[rkey].restName}
                    </button>
                    <div className="rst_list_position">
                        {rlist[rkey].address}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Link>
    )
}

return (<div>
    {rlist_tmp}
</div>);
}

export default Restaurant_Item;
```

This component get object from state. These state is reflected on div tag.
When user clicked this div tag which about restaurant, page change with detail page that contain restaurant detail information.

This is detail page.

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import Restaurant_result_axios from './Restaurant_result_axios.js';

import backicon from "../assets/backicon.png";

const Restaurant_result = ({data}) => {
  console.log(data)
  return (
    <div>
        <Link to="./restaurant_list"><img className="backicon" src={backicon} alt="backicon"/> 
 </Link>
        <div className="rst_result_prom"/>
        <div className="rst_result_cell">
            <div>
                <div className="rst_result_name">
                  
                </div>
                <div className="rst_result_position">
                  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
);
};

export default Restaurant_result;
```

But I found some problem. If user clicked div tag, router change page before execute goDetail function. I don't know how resolve this problem. Can I excute goDetail function before link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try my code below, in `RestaurantItem Component` i remove `<Link></Link>` from this component, because you want handleClick first using `goDetail` function for getting some detail about what are users clicking data. so i import `useHistory` to replace `Link` and put in const history. And i put `history` into `goDetail` Function. its look same like your `Link` before. you can followiing my code here:

`RestaurantItem Component`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function Restaurant_Item({ rlist }) {
  const history = useHistory();
  const [rstData, setResData] = useState([]);
  const [linkName, setLinkName] = useState("abc");
  let rlist_tmp = [];

  const goDetail = (rkey) => {
    const data = rlist[rkey];
    const link = rlist[rkey].restName;

    setResData(data);
    setLinkName(link);
    history.push({
      pathname: "/restaurant_result",
      search: `?sort=${link}`,
      state: { data: data }
    });
  };

  for (let rkey in rlist) {
    rlist_tmp.push(
      <div className="rst_list_cell" onClick={() => goDetail(rkey)}>
        <div key={rkey}>
          <button className="rst_list_name">{rlist[rkey].restName}</button>
          <div className="rst_list_position">{rlist[rkey].address}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return <div>{rlist_tmp}</div>;
}

export default Restaurant_Item;
```

for the `RestaurantResult Component`  import `useLocation` to access state where passsing from `RestaurantItem Component` through `history.push`.

`RestaurantResult Component`

```
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

import backicon from "../assets/backicon.png";

const Restaurant_result = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/restaurant_list">
        <img className="backicon" src={backicon} alt="backicon" />
      </Link>
      <div className="rst_result_prom" />
      <div className="rst_result_cell">
        <div>
          <div className="rst_result_name">{location.state.data.restName}</div>
          <div className="rst_result_position">
            {location.state.data.address}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Restaurant_result;
```

I just test it in code sandbox here is the link:
[This is Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/silly-darkness-ex3fu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Thank you so much! I solve this problem with your soloution!!!!! I didn't think useHistory.